# Output cutting off when using CLaiR in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rascal

I just installed Rascal and Eclipse (4.7.2) on Windows 10.
I've imported CLaiR (C Language Analysis in Rascal) and am trying to parse an existing C program

rascal>import lang::cpp::AST;
ok
rascal>parseCpp(|file:///c:/users/user/testme.cpp|)

I get a little over a screenful of information.  The last line looks truncated and the last 3 characters are ...

Am I right? How do I increase how much is shown?
I've tried:
1. Windows, Preferences, Terminal, Terminal Buffer Lines = 1000000
2. Windows, Preferences, Run/Debug, Console, Console Buffer Size = 1000000

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We indeed truncate the output of the result of an REPL command.

If you pass the value into `iprintln` (`i` for indented), you will get the full value. There is also `iprintToFile` to write it to a file. Another option is to use the functions `util::ValueUI` to view the value as either a collapsable `tree`, indented `text`, or a `graph`.